# While converting from Excel to PDF

Tags: java, excel, pdf

I have used the following code for converting an XLSX workbook to PDF....The code is working fine..I mean PDF I am getting PDF as output but on the top of each page of PDF it is showing  API information...How to remove this header message?

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("C:\\abc.xlsx");
workbook.save("c:\\FileTemp\\MyPdfFile.pdf", FileFormatType.PDF);
```

The message is like this

> "Evaluation Only. Created with Aspose.Cells for Java. Copyright 2003 -
>   2018 Aspose Pty Ltd.

Answer (score 1):

This is an evaluation watermark which will be always embedded (when using the component without a valid license set) when you generate Excel, PDF or image file via Aspose.Cells APIs. You need to purchase the license and specify the license in your code at the start before using any other Aspose.Cells APIs. When using a valid license, there would be no such limitation or other restrictions whatsoever.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.